# How does current work in this instance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

If current has two ways to flow in a single circuit, let’s say one path has a resistor of 5 Ohms and the other has no resistors whatsoever, will current still flow in both of the conductors?

Can anyone help me with this question since the answer for the reading of ammeter is 4.5A but the solution implies that the current only flows through the switch and the 5 Ohms resistor is ignored (when calculating the effective resistance)

[image]

Comment: Why the closure? OP is not asking for the answer, but rather the physical reason why the 5 $\Ohm$ resistor is ignorable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current takes the path of least resistance, so when there is a switch across the 5$\Omega$ resistor, it is "shorted" and the current bypasses the resistance. Thus, the only effective resistance in the circuit is that of the parallel arrangement of 2 and 4 ohm resistors. So to calculate the current one should find the net resistance of the parallel configuration:$${1\over R}={1\over 2}\Omega^{-1}+{1\over 4}\Omega^{-1}={3\over 4}\Omega^{-1}.$$ Now, from Ohm's law, $V=IR$, one may calculate the current $I$:$$I={V\over R}=6V\cdot {3\over 4}\Omega^{-1}=4.5A.$$